# Excel 2013 Calculating Time difference in cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good day. I am having an issue calculating the time difference between 2 cell values. The user puts the time in military time, and the cell value displays as A.M. or P.M. This is done with formatting the cell, but the code I have works great, unless the user puts in the same time in the "Start Time" column & "End Time" column. If the "Start Time" is 06:00, and the "End Time" is 06:00, the calculation should display "24:00" but it doesn't. It displays as 00:00. Can someone assist me with this? The code is as follows:

```
=IF(SUM(A13:B13)>0,IF(B13<A13,B13+1,B13)-A13,IF(B13=A13,24,""))
```

Column A is Start Time, and column B is End Time. Column C has the formula above to calculate the time difference. Much help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This formula makes no sense... What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to get the difference between them, the formula is just `= A13-B13`. If you want the formula to be 24 when the difference is 0, then just do `= IF(A13=B13,24,A13-B13)`.

Comment: The original formula I was using is =IF(B13<A13,B13+1,B13)-A13. This does great except if the value=0, I need it to display 24, instead of 0:00. All cells are formatted as Time h:mm. The formula you suggested still displays a value of 0:00

Comment: The time calculation is based on 24 hrs per day...

Comment: Considering my formula is practically as simple as it gets, if that is displaying 0:00 and you want it to display 24:00, then the problem is with the *formatting*, not the formula. My guess is that the formula actually returns the value 24, but the formatting recognizes 24 as the same as 0:00 military time which is why the formatting is taking over.

Comment: I just confirmed that with a simple test. I formatted the cell in military time and entered the value 24 into the cell, and 0:00 is displayed. Therefore, it is a problem with your formatting.

Comment: I've tried reformatting all 3 cells and Custom h:mm seems to be the only one that works properly, sooooo....I'm still getting a display of 0:00 for 24 hrs time lapse. Not saying your formula wouldn't work, but it seems to be not working for me

Comment: I think you missed my point. The cell will never display 24:00 because if the cell evaluates to 24, then the formatting will automatically change it to 0:00.

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks pnuts!